# What happens when two tyranids from different hives encounter?

Tags: warhammer-40k

From the universe of Warhammer 40K, what happens when two tyranids from different hives encounter?

Two subjects from different tyranid fleets/hives/minds encounter each other with no interfering forces. What happens?

I don't know much about the setting or the workings of w40k, just some factions, there's an Emperor of Humankind, maybe some rebels (if the Horus Heresy Series runs on this fiction-verse), that there are green Orks that do things with guns, that there are the tyranids that are something like an invasion of the galaxy and that the methot of FTL travelling is through an alternate reality full of demons/hell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different options depending on the situation of their meetings. The Tyranids are controlled by a hive mind that influences all of them to different degrees, with the smaller ones needing to be next to synapse creatures or they resort to their instinct of either hiding or hunting.

So if two smaller ones encounter each other without a synapse creature in range, they will resort to their base instinct. Some will try to eat the other one, some will try to hide.

If two hive fleets run into each other and have synapse creature, the hive mind can either combine them or cause them to fight each other. It is theorized that they might fight to see which fleet is stronger. The stronger one can eat the losers and grow more of the winner's version. That way the hive mind always has the optimal army.

https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Tyranid has more info on them, and the lexicanum site is a great resource for everything 40k